# How can I force the use of the given table name for a jointable?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, relationship

I'm using Spring data JPA and am setting up my very first ManyToMany relationship. I have the first object 'User' defined as:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SMX0_PAR_USER", schema = "SMX0_INPUT_DAY")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String userID;
    private String username;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "SMX0_PAR_USER_ROLE",
        schema = "SMX0_INPUT_DAY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "userID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "roleID")
    )
    private Set<Role> roleSet;


    protected User(){

    }

    public User(String userID, String username){
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
    }
```

The second object 'Role' is defined as:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SMX0_PAR_ROLE", schema = "SMX0_INPUT_DAY")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private int roleID;
    private String rolename;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleSet")
    private Set<User> userSet;


    protected Role(){

    }

    public Role(int roleID, String role){
        this.roleID = roleID;
        this.rolename = role;
    }
```

- There are getters and setters for all fields in both classes.
- Fetching the Users without the many-to-many relationship with the Roles works perfectly.

When trying to access a page with the following thymeleaf code in it:

```
 <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
     <td th:text="${user.getUserID()}">user ID</td>
     <td th:text="${user.getUsername()}">username</td>
     <td><span th:each="role : ${user.getRoleSet()}">
         <span th:text="${role.getRolename()}">rolename</span>
     </span></td>
</tr>
```

I get exceptions:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//module/userManagement/index.html]")
…
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: could not extract ResultSet
…
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
…
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ROLESET0_"."ROLE_ID": invalid identifier
```

What is happening here, why is there a reference to something like "ROLESET0_" when I explicitly set the join table name as something else? How can I force the use of the table name which I already gave?

Comment: please share your import statements

Comment: `ROLESET0_` is an alias that hibernate assigns in the query it generates. Might be helpful if you set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see the full query that hibernate is producing. You can also set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` to make it more readable.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I've added the import statements as you requested

Comment: @AndrewMairose please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it -> it is indeed an alias, not the table named used in the query, which becomes obvious when you see the actual query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROLESET0_` is an alias that hibernate assigns in the query it generates. Might be helpful if you set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to see the full query that hibernate is producing. You can also set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the annotation `@Column (name = "YourColumnName")` for all  fields in two classes.

Also the `referencedColumnName` parameter should be the name of the  column referenced by this foreign key column.

```
    public class User {
       @Id
       @Column(name = "YourColumnName")
       private int roleID;
       @Column(name = "YourColumnName")
       private String rolename;

       @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
        name = "SMX0_PAR_USER_ROLE",
        schema = "SMX0_INPUT_DAY",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "YourColumnName"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName ="YourColumnName"))
        .....

        }

   public class Role {

       @Id
       @Column(name = "YourColumnName")
       private int roleID;
       @Column(name = "YourColumnName")
       private String rolename;
       .......

       }
```